# How to set batch_size, steps per epoch and validation steps

Tags: keras, theano

I am writing cnn using Keras with theano backend. I dont understand how to set values for batch_size, steps_per_epoch and validation_steps. If i have 240,000 images in the training set and 60,000 images in the test set, what must be the value of batch_size, steps_per_epoch and validation_steps?